# Problems with AdMob integration into Android App

Tags: android, sdk, admob, instructions

I am quite new into Java and Android Apps, so , while this may be cake for others it gives me some headache .
The app should load , play a sound file , and close . And it works fine without the AdMob .
With the AdMob it starts , vibrates once ( it doesnt in the normal version ) , runs normally , and then gets stuck , vibrates 3 times , and closes throwing a " Sorry! The application NAME ( process PROCESS.NAME ) has stopped unexpectedly . Please try again " .

I`m on my second app , and my first AdMob integration.

The SDK instructions I followed : http://www.admob.com/docs/AdMob_Android_SDK_Instructions.pdf

What I did :
- Registered
- Got the SDK 
- Added the .jar
- Added the **pub ID** , **AdMobActivity definition** and **Track Market Installs** code from the SDK Instructions at the end of AndroidManifest.xml and edited the pub ID
- Added the internet permission
- Added "ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" too
- Added "AdMob AdView Attributes" to attrs.xml ( I use Eclipse , so I first tried to add this to res/values/strings.xml , then made a new xml and added the code to it )

If full code is needed I will edit this post. Any help is appreciated .
Thank you in advance
Chris
(LogCat throws two small errors without the AdMob files ( I //-ed the import and AdView ) )
(LogCat WITH AdMob throws this )

```
12-11 14:50:00.266: ERROR/beep(284): started0
12-11 14:50:00.346: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{seven.kitty.purr/seven.kitty.purr.KittyPurr}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at seven.kitty.purr.KittyPurr.onCreate(KittyPurr.java:20)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
12-11 14:50:00.368: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(284):     ... 11 more
12-11 14:50:00.407: ERROR/dalvikvm(284): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Editing with full .java and XML codes . I suck at Java, it's so diferent than AS , PHP , JavaScript and other web languages I usually use

KittyPurr.java

```
package seven.kitty.purr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.admob.android.ads.AdManager;
import com.admob.android.ads.AdView;

public class KittyPurr extends Activity
{
  private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
   playAudio();



  }

  private void playAudio () {
    try {
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.purrr);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
    Log.e("beep","started0");
    mMediaPlayer.start();

    AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
    adView.requestFreshAd();

    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
         finish();
      }
    });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("beep", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
    mMediaPlayer.release();
    mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
  }
}
```

main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/seven.kitty.purr"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/ad"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">
<attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />
<attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />
<attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" />
<attr name="keywords" format="string" />
<attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Plz post the output of logcat.

Answer (score 0):

> Added the jar

means you add the file to /libs? If not, do so.

EDIT:

You are using the wrong `onCreate`. It should be:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 ...
}
```

Comment: yeah , I have added that to /libs , and added the .jar to the project too . just like it sais in the .pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to add the following this in xml and if you want to test it in emulator
  then u need to set the **adrequest.setTestDevice(true)**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        **xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"**
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **myapp:adUnitId="Your Admob ID"
    myapp:adSize="BANNER"**
    />
    </LinearLayout>


in the AndroidManifest.xml you need to add the following thing

<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

and one thing you need to consider that u need to compile project with android 3.2 or above
```